# Filter not found urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var url_array = Array(
    'url1.html',
    'url2.html',
    'url3.html',
    'url4.html',
    'url5.html'
);
```

How can i filter invalid/not found/404 urls from the array.

there should be a function with takes that url_array and return an array with valid/found urls.

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://addyosmani.com/blog/catch404/)
This is the library that will catch 404 error...

Comment: can u help me creating a function with this library which can return an array with valid urls?